# Django & reportlab : show a generated pdf on a div in the same page

Tags: django, templates, django-views, reportlab

I'm generating pdfs using reportlab, my view looks like :

```
def statut(request,id):
# Set up response
infoSte=sarl.objects.get(id=id)
associe=Associee.objects.all().filter(id_sarl=id)

associe_gerant=0
response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename="form_letter.pdf"'
buff = BytesIO()
menu_pdf = SimpleDocTemplate(buff, rightMargin=60,
                            leftMargin=60, topMargin=65, bottomMargin=65)
story = []
#APPENDING PDF CONTENT ..
story.append(Paragraph(denomination_so,styleN))
menu_pdf.multiBuild(story, canvasmaker=FooterCanvas)
response.write(buff.getvalue())
buff.close()
return response
```

This view is renderer using the url bellow

```
url(r'^pdfstatut/(?P<id>\d+)$',views.statut, name='statutJuridique'),
```

when exacuting this url the pdf is generated on a dedicated page. 
What I need is when I click on the link `statut` on the left of the page, the pdf shows on the section in the right side :

[image]

How can I achieve such result when my view only return a response which is only a pdf.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JS called PDF object, as described here:
[Pdf object](https://pdfobject.com/#the-why)

or non JS, as described here: [Static](https://pdfobject.com/static/)